# Kubernetes persistent volume on Docker Desktop (Windows)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows 10. For the purposes of development, I want to expose a local folder to a container. When running the container in Docker, I do this by specifying the volume flag (-v).

How do I achieve the same when running the container in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) Volume type in your pod`s spec to mount a file or directory from the host node’s filesystem, where hostPath.path field should be of following format to accept Windows like paths:

- /W/fooapp/influxdb
- //W/fooapp/influxdb
- /////W/fooapp/influxdb

Please check [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59876) github issue explaining peculiarities of Kubernetes Volumes on Windows.
I assume also that you have enabled [Shared Drives](https://web.archive.org/web/20181231025453/http://peterjohnlightfoot.com/docker-for-windows-on-hyper-v-fix-the-host-volume-sharing-issue/) feature in your Docker for Windows installation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This works for me, and seems to be the best quick and dirty way to share my local folder. I managed to share my folder using "/c/temp/data" as the hostpath. I had tried this before, but it turns out that I was running into the Shared drives issue that you mention (as I was attempting to share the drive using an Active Directory account).

Comment: Hello, this seems to solve the error for me, anyway the path ofthe folder that gets monted is not what I expected it to be. For example using `path: /C/config` and `type: DirectoryOrCreate` the folder gets created and everything works, but I have no idea where the folder is in the host filesystem (it is not in C:/config)

Comment: For those encountering my same problem (previous comment), check this: github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023 
And the solution basically was to use: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/dir/otherDir
(source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812948/volume-mounts-not-working-kubernetes-and-wsl-2-and-docker)

Comment: Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018631/kubernetes-on-docker-for-windows-persistent-volume-with-hostpath-gives-operatio

Answer (score 10):

Using k8s 1.21.5 the following type of path worked for me:

```
/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/PATH/TO/FILE
```

Digging through this github issue helped me resolve which path to use:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59876

Comment: is anyone available to comment on WHY this works?  it just worked for me, but no clue why

Comment: this is annoying, if I use /c/path, I get "operation not permitted" error running a simple ls, this magical path works  (dockerdesktop with kubernetes on wsl2)

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is on the github link above.

> The folder mount for `/run/desktop/mnt/host/c` does not exist on the distro you installed in WSL2 - on that WSL2 distro, the mount point to your C:\ drive is the more obvious `/mnt/c`.
>
> Realize that Kubernetes and Docker **are not installed in your installed WSL2 distro**. Instead, Docker Desktop for Windows creates its own WSL2 VM called `docker-desktop` and installs Docker and Kubernetes on that VM. Then Docker Desktop for Windows installs the `docker` and `kubectl` CLIs on your WSL2 distro (and also on your Windows machine) and configures them all to point to the Docker and Kubernetes instances it created on the `docker-desktop` VM. This docker-desktop VM is hosting Docker and Kubernetes and also contains the `/run/desktop/mnt/host/c` mount point to your Windows C:\ drive and that can be used by your containers to persist data.
>
> You can remote into the `docker-desktop` VM and see the `/run/desktop/mnt/host/c` mount point and folder structure by following the instructions (and discussion) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117039/11057678:
>
> ```
> docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
> ```