# equivalent of "minikube ssh" with docker-for-desktop Kubernetes node

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using Docker for Mac but currently only using it for its Kubernetes cluster. The Kubernetes cluster's single node is named **docker-for-desktop**.

I'm currently going through a Kubernetes tutorial on Persistent Volumes (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) and as part of that, I'm setting up a **hostPath** persistent volume. It seems like the way this works is, you create a path on the Kubernetes Node itself and you can use that as your persistent volume for development and testing purposes.

To do that, the tutorial instructs you to SSH into your Kubernetes node itself and create a path which can then be turned into a persistent volume. The only problem is, I have no idea how to SSH directly into the Kubernetes node itself (not a container). The equivalent for minikube would just be `minikube ssh`. I can `kubectl describe` the node, but I only get an internal IP address, not an external one. So I have no idea how to address it in an `ssh` command.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739560/how-to-access-the-vm-created-by-dockers-hyperkit/51636201).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the VM created by docker's HyperKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739560/how-to-access-the-vm-created-by-dockers-hyperkit)

Answer (score 12):

Comment in the OP should get credit for this but i'll add again so i find it easier in a few months:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

From https://github.com/justincormack/nsenter1/blob/master/README.md

> ... this is useful when you are running a lightweight, container-optimized Linux distribution such as LinuxKit... you are demonstrating with Docker for Mac, for example, your containers are not running on your host directly, but are running instead inside of a minimal Linux OS virtual machine specially built for running containers, i.e., LinuxKit. But being a lightweight environment, LinuxKit isn't running sshd, so how do you get access to a shell so you can run nsenter to inspect the namespaces for the process running as pid 1?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing. I am playing around with PV/PVC and really just wanted to get "eyes on" on the thing that's being stored.

I am running Kubernetes 1.22.5 and Docker Desktop 4.5.0

**To gain access to the docker-desktop node**

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

**My PV**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

**Finding the Directory /mnt/data**

There were quite a few different locations and manually sniffing was a little overwhelming. It's search to just search for what you're looking for:

Search for "data" directory

```
find / -type d -name "data"
```

This will return a list of matches. I had quite a few results. But now you can search your terminal for "mnt/data" and there you are.

Mine was at `/containers/services/docker/rootfs/mnt/data`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer when running k8s on Docker Desktop, then I tried `docker ps` and to my surprise, the containers of my pod was there.

So I just ssh like you would with any docker container

```
$ docker exec -it 0b83055dac1b /bin/bash
```

Comment: I think OP wants to ssh to the k8's master node which in his case is docker-desktop

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**

If the node were created by docker-machine using VirtualBox, would be similar to minikube, with the command:

`docker-machine ssh default`

If you are using the default `HyperKit` driver for MAC, there isn't an VM like VirtualBox, but you should be able to open the shell with following command:

`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

**Original:**

If you have direct access to the node and the certificate, it is as simple as a command like this:

```
ssh -i certificatename 10.0.0.1
```

or

```
ssh -i certificatename docker@10.0.0.1
```

take a look into [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) post.

If you are running Kubernetes in a cloud provider, you should use the provider tools to do that.

An example is the Google Cloud you would use:

`gcloud compute ssh <NODE_NAME> --zone <ZONE>`

Azure and Aws also have similar options, you can also use their portal for it.

Other alternative, is using a bastian\helper container in the cluster to connect to the nodes without setting up network permissions, it works on cloud or on premises clusters.

Something like:

`kubectl run -it --rm aks-ssh --image=debian`

This will run a container with bash, then you have to install the ssh client `apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-client -y` copy the client certificate to the container and ssh into the node like `ssh -i id_rsa azureuser@10.240.0.4`.

There is a nice example in the [AKS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh)

Comment: Doesn't the question ask specifically about Docker for Mac? Your answer seems to address the issue for a more generic installation on Cloud

Comment: Correct @PierreB., the problem is that Docker for Mac doesn't seem to expose a DNS name or anything like that. This answer doesn't address that point.