# How to ssh into docker-desktop kubernetes node?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, docker-desktop

Able to ssh to minikube, but not in docker-desktop node in Kubernetes ?
[image]

Comment: You should almost never need to; in the Kubernetes environments I'm used to working in, as a developer, I don't have access to the underlying Nodes at all.  What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: There could be N number of reasons for someone to ask this kind of questions. We should not be relating that with prod scenario. for ex: the OP might want to explore the k8s manifests inside the control plane.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117039/11058704

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it?

Answer (score -1):

From a minikube instance, the idea is not to ssh to docker desktop, but to use docker directly through:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

See "[Goodbye Docker Desktop, Hello Minikube!](https://itnext.io/goodbye-docker-desktop-hello-minikube-3649f2a1c469)" from [Abhinav Sonkar](https://twitter.com/abhiguitar) as an example.

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/4800/1*BWP9sVNTNn01xDlvGKNY0g.png]

Comment: This is NOT anything to do with minikube!!!