# Unable to create file under the Node - Docker desktop (Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

So I want to create a directory under the node kubernetes simulated via docker-desktop

When I am trying to do so I am getting this error

/ # mkdir pod-volume
mkdir: can't create directory 'pod-volume': Read-only file system

Any idea How can I fix this inside docker-desktop (used for kubernetes simulation)

Comment: I managed to work around this by creating files/directories and working with them under /tmp dir

Comment: Yeah. I did the same

Answer (score 2):

> The Kubernetes server runs locally within your Docker instance, is not
> configurable, and is a single-node cluster.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/kubernetes/

> Docker Desktop offers a Kubernetes installation with a solid host
> integration aiming to work without any user intervention.

By the way this is a great article about how it works under the hood:

https://www.docker.com/blog/how-kubernetes-works-under-the-hood-with-docker-desktop/

However, don't know why you are trying to do this, but it's not a good practice. If you want to deal with volumes there is a lot of articles on the internet about this, here is one stack overflow link that could help: [Kubernetes persistent volume on Docker Desktop (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073794/kubernetes-persistent-volume-on-docker-desktop-windows)

Hope this has helped you,
Bguess